# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences) in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, plugins

Both IOS and Android build was working fine. But recently when I tried to run my app in IOS device I got this error and the screen keeps loading in splash screen.
I tried multiple ways like,

- flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- deleting pubspec.lock file
- deleting podfile.lock file
  nothing solved my issue.
  But when I tried this method,
- SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues({});

The app will run in ios, but when we kill the app and open it again all the values stored in shared preferences will be null.

Comment: if you have old flutter version then check according SharedPreferences version

Comment: Hey, guys I fixed this issue by checking the version of shared_preferences and flutter_foreground_task. These both are depended on each other. 
You can see the changelog of flutter_foreground_task : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task/changelog

Answer (score 0):

You can try these steps:

1. flutter clean
2. flutter pub get
3. Invalid Caches and Restart

Comment: Tried this multiple times, it is not working for me. As I mentioned it in the question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: did you solved this error?? I have the same error.. been a month now and it only occur on ios..

Comment: @anas - Hey, I fixed this issue by checking the version of shared_preferences and flutter_foreground_task. These both are depended on each other. You can see the changelog of flutter_foreground_task : pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_task/changelog